# What's the wire size needed to supply a 125amp sub panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel

Will #6 stranded CU THHN be sufficient to supply a 125amp 12 space 24 circuit sub panel that is 80 feet away?

Comment: There are any number of wire-size calculators online that will get you to the right choice.  I'll also add that for runs such as this one, AL wires are often significantly less expensive than CU.

Comment: What loads are you serving from this subpanel?

Comment: To put it another way: Do you have a load calculation requiring a 125A supply? Or is it "a 125A panel is cheap & easy for this application but I really only need {50|60|70}A, etc."? The breaker in the main panel on the feed to this subpanel is what determines the maximum current and, therefore, the minimum wire size.

Comment: And possibly the most important question can you get a 125a breaker for your main panel to feed this sub.

Comment: You realize "24 circuit" is nonsense because you can't use double-stuff breakers anymore.   That's only a 12 space panel.  Please make sure that the number of *spaces* is plenty for your needs.  Spaces are very cheap when buying the panel and very expensive when you later run out! I prefer to finish a panel with 1/2 of spaces still free.  *If you need to go up a "nameplate" size to 150A or 200A, **that is fine***.

Comment: We're confused by what you mean by "125A panel".  First it's perfectly cool to have a subpanel size (100A, 125A, 200A, 225A) that is *larger* than the breaker supplying it (e.g. 60A or 70A).  That is desired so you have plenty of spaces.   However your feed wire is only good for 65A so we just want to make sure that makes sense given your application.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes you can feed a 125 amp panel with 14 gauge Wire and a 15 amp breaker but that would be silly.
We need to know your loads to fully help you.

If you only want 65 amps yes #6 is ok you can feed a 125 amp sub with a smaller wire size and breaker But more information is needed I don’t know if any residential panels rated for 90c but most are rated for 75c.

If you truly need 125 amp make sure you can get a double pole breaker that fits your panel before purchasing the wire some panels 100 amp is as big as you can find.
larger wire sizes aluminum wire is less expensive and makes sense I usually make the change to aluminum at 6 awg copper Meaning #4 aluminum and up for residential.  Some of my reasoning on the size /type change is based on past experience with grades of aluminum no longer sold some is smaller aluminum breaks more easily and the reason I change once larger, the last reason larger than #6 wire size the wires can be identified with colored tape 6 and smaller I have to have multiple colors.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you gave, no, #6 AWG THHN wouldn't be sufficient. You must have sufficient load to be calling for a 125 Amp panel and #6 is good for 75 Amps if your panel is rated for 90 degrees C., 65 Amps at 75 degrees C.